# Stripe.js v3 card elements. How to change Input Type to password?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, stripe.js

Stripe.js v3 inserts its own input fields to input card number. There are options to either use single input field (card-element) or separate them as cardExpiry or cardCVC etc.

The problem is I want the cvc and expiry inputs to be of type='password'.

But there seems to be no way in stripe.js v3 to change the field input time.

(ref : https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js#the-elements-object)

Comment: This is not something supported by Stripe at the moment.

Comment: Then is there any alternative? Should we switch to stripe v2 instead?

Comment: I'd ask Stripe's support team: https://support.stripe.com/email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, koopajah is right.

I emailed and asked stripe support team. They replied at the moment with Stripe.js v3 this is not possible.

I will stick to v2 for now. But Stripe said that they will pass the suggestion to their development team.